# How to write in specific place of line text PYTHON

Tags: python, text, tkinter, python-3.4

I have the following code on python 3.4:

```
abrir = open("C:\\Users\\Jesus_Multilaser\\Desktop\\productos.txt","r+") # KNOW IT OPEN MY TEXT ARCHIVE
cantidad=cantidadBox.get() #IT GETS TEXT FROM ENTRY

leer = abrir.readlines() #READ LINES OF MY TEXT ARCHIVE
archivo = leer[0] #SELECT A SPECIFIC LINE
ubicacion = archivo.split("'") #SEPARATE 
claveReg = ubicacion[0] #GET A SPECIFIC PLACE
```

Now I want to write over "claveReg" place
I try with:

```
claveReg.write(cantidad)
crear.close()
```

But it doesn't work.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what _specifically_ goes wrong?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between strings and file objects; reading the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) might help. As it stands, this is like asking us why there's no hot water coming out of your hammer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to write to a string. Instead of `running claveReg.write()`, try `type(claveReg)`, or even better, just `print claveReg`. I suspect you'll find that it's just a string.

Since it is just a string, it doesn't have any link back to its location in the file. Instead, you should read the entire file into memory, make your changes, then overwrite the file. This isn't a Python limitation either, it has to do with how the OS handles file changes.

You might be able to overwrite specific areas of a file by using [`file.seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) and `file.write`, but I would do so with extreme caution since it's seeking by bytes, not lines.